# MySQL- Count the most occurring string in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Here is my table called "sport" and the column "club", I want to know the number of the most occurring string.

```
club
--------
club(A)
club(A)
club(A)
club(B)
club(C)
```

The result should be like this :

```
club       count    
-------- ------------
club(A)      3
```

so club(A) occurred 3 times, more than the other clubs.

How can I query for this?

Comment: select field, count(field) group by field desc

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Post what you've tried in your original question.

Comment: @MosheL: Submit as an answer

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: OP seems new to SO. May not be knowing how to present what he needs and what he did.

Comment: @Ravinder The [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is just a click away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following query.  It selects the club and the number of times it occurs in the table.  Then it groups and orders the rows based on which club they are in and the number of occurances.  Then it returns the top row.

```
SELECT club, COUNT(club)
FROM sport
GROUP BY club
ORDER BY COUNT(club) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Here is an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a79fc/1)

Answer (score 2):

And the correct answer is:

```
SELECT club, COUNT(club) as `count`
FROM sport
GROUP BY club
ORDER BY COUNT(club) desc
LIMIT 1;
```

You need to sort by the count in descending order to get the most common value.